# Ionic Zoom View

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, ionic-framework

I want to popup and zoom a contact image,for which i have found ionic zoom view.
 I have run "bower install ionic zoom view" and have added the dependencies in my index file

```
    <script src="lib/ionic-zoom-view/dist/ionic-zoom-view.js"></script>
 <script src="lib/ionic-zoom-view/src/ionic-zoom-view.js"></script>
```

When i Add ionic-zoom-view" in my app.js file

```
   angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'starter.controllers', 'starter.services', 'ionic-zoom-view','chart.js'])
```

the code doesnt seem to run with an error.

> Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.3/$injector/modulerr?p0=starter&p1=Error%3A…%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8100%2Flib%2Fionic%2Fjs%2Fionic.bundle.min.js%3A50%3A339)

i am stuck here, what wrong am i doing?

Comment: Please post your stacktrace and not only the final error

Comment: Still hard to tell. When I had injection errors usually a version incompatibility was the cause. Maybe check that ? Sorry I don't have another clue...

Comment: is this the right way, to add a directive?

Comment: Yep, as far is I can tell, see https://github.com/AlexDisler/ionic-zoom-view. Did you use bower for installing?

Comment: Yes,
Do u know any other method to Popup an image in ionic fw?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97862/discussion-between-ueq-and-sameed).